Ubuntu 24.04 lts will work with E2180 processor
Can anyone kindly help me with running Ubuntu 24.04 LTS in Intel Pentium Dual Core processor E2180 4 GB RAM and 250 GB SSD. will the configutarion be enough for light office work, web surffing and watching videos in youtube.

My suggestion: https://sourceforge.net/projects/mx-linux/

This question is similar to: Will my device work with Ubuntu?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
